# unity3d oncollisionenter doesn't work with rigidbody and nocollider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have rigidbody2D on arrow and enemy.  both are at 0 z coordinates. I don't want to use colliders as I want the enemies to be able to stack on top of each other.  When I turn colliders on, the code works and the objects get destroyed.  Is there another function I could use that works with rigidbodies only?  I thought OnCollicionEnter worked with rigidbodies.

arrow

```
function OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D) {
Debug.Log("I hit something");
    coll.gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", 10);
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

enemy

```
var health = 20;
function ApplyDamage (damage : float)
{

health -= damage;

if ( health <= 0)
{
Destroy(gameObject);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collisions require one `Rigidbody` to happen. In your `OnCollisionEnter` you could check if the `coll` parameter has a rigidbody attached. And only then apply the damage.

Comment: They both have Rigidbody2D attached to them.  Seems to only work with colliders.  I can't get it to work without adding colliders.  How do I check the coll parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a box collider to the enemy and set rigidbody2D to "is kinematic."  This allowed the enemies to group up on top of each other while I could still collide.  Also used `OnTriggerEnter2D(coll: Collider2D)` instead of `OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D)`.